# write result of rank loop in r

Tags: r, loops, rank

I've been hitting walls trying to write the results of a loop to a csv.  I'm trying to rank data within each of 20 columns. The loop I'm using is:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(testing_file)) { 
  print(rank(testing_file[[i]]))
}
```

This works and prints expected results to screen. I've tried a lot of methods suggested in various discussions to write this result to file or data frame, most with no luck. 
I'll just include my most promising lead, which returns only one column of correct data, with a column heading of "testing":

```
for (i in 1:ncol(testing_file)) { 
  testing<- (rank(testing_file[[i]]))
  testingdf <- as.data.frame(testing)
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works:

```
testage<- data.frame(matrix(, nrow=73, ncol=20))  #This creates an empty data 
frame that the ranked results will go into
for (i in 1:ncol(testing_file)) { 
testage[i] <- rank(testing_file[[i]])
print(testage[i])
} #this is the loop that ranks data within each column 
colnames(testage) <- colnames(testing_file) #take the column names from the 
original file and apply them to the ranked file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm bad with nested loops so I'd try:

```
testing_file <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 15:11)
testing <- as.data.frame(lapply(seq_along(testing_file), function (x) 
rank(testing_file[, x])))

> testing_file
 x  y
1 1 15
2 2 14
3 3 13
4 4 12
5 5 11
```

and gets you out of messy nested loops. Did you want to check results of rank() prior to writing to csv?

or just wrap it in a write.csv, the colnames will be the original df colnames:

```
> write.csv(testing <- as.data.frame(lapply(seq_along(testing_file), 
function (x) rank(testing_file[, x]))), "testing.csv", quote = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I've tried these options but get the error: 
    Unsupported use of matrix or array for column indexing

Comment: I found a solution that works:  testage<- data.frame(matrix(, nrow=73, ncol=20))
for (i in 1:ncol(testing_file)) { 
testage[i] <- rank(testing_file[[i]])
print(testage[i])
}
colnames(testage) <- colnames(testing_file)